# advice MySql tables design

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey guys i was wondering if there is a better way to go about some mysql tables.
I have to evaluate (in a php app) how a task was completed based on 9 attributes The problem is that once a year the columns might change (the naming not the number of evaluation fields)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `grades` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `score_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `task_number` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `assigned_to` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `completed_at` date NOT NULL,
  `priority` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `worknotes` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `client_com` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `closure_info` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `category` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ci` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timecard` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `resolution_time` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `validated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT
CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
COMMIT;
```

So my first thought is to create another table with the attributes name and have 2 tables like this

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `grades` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `score_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `task_number` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `assigned_to` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `completed_at` date NOT NULL,
  `grade1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `grade2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `grade3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `grade4` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `grade5` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `grade6` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `grade7` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `grade8` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `grade9` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `validated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
COMMIT;
```

and

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `evaluation_fields` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO `evaluation_fields` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Priority'),
(2, 'Worknotes'),
(3, 'Client Com'),
(4, 'Closure information'),
(5, 'Status management'),
(6, 'Category management'),
(7, 'CI identification', ),
(8, 'Timecard management'),
(9, 'Resolution Time');
COMMIT;
```

How would you recommend going about this? Thx in advance for your time. Hope i am making some kind of sense

Comment: Your column names should not be changing once a year, or ideally, ever.  Maybe explain whay your database is trying to store.

Comment: I am storing the evaluation of some tasks based on some criteria, i know that they should not changed that is why  i thought of a second table with the column names and when i need to change them i just do it in the second table

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above, say, 2) alarm bells should start ringing.

Comment: that is why i ended up asking you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t want to change the structure every year or so. You need to define a design that is flexible enough to fit your use case.

I suggest that you should be able to manage this with 3 tables :

**attributes** contains all the attributes that can be used to evaluate a task. It is basically a referential table, whose content is modified only when new evaluation attributes need to be created (so about once a year). Like :

```
id        - primary key
name  - name of the evaluation attribute
```

**grades** is meant to store the evaluation results. There is one row for each evaluation, with a few fields containing the master data of the evaluation, like :

```
id     - primary key
score_id
task_number
assigned_to
location 
completed_at
priority
```

**evaluations** is meant to store the details of each evaluation. It has one line for each attribute that was used for each evaluation, and refers to both above tables using foreign keys, like :

```
id                    - primary key 
grade_id         - foreign key to column id in table grades
evaluation_id  - foreign key to column id in table attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 3 tables one for tasks and its attribute, the other is for evaluation fields containing the name and any other attribute of this evaluation and the relation between this one and the tasks is going to be many to many this means the third table should basically have the id of the task and the id of the evaluation field and other attributes as you need